# rosbag 'UnicodeDecodeError'

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have some rosbags. Most of them seem to be okay according to 'rosbag check '. But a few of them cause the check to be aborted in the middle of the bag with the error below.

What is the best way to avoid this decoding error?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/bin/rosbag", line 35, in <module>
    rosbag.rosbagmain()
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 863, in rosbagmain
    cmds[cmd](argv[2:])
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 452, in check_cmd
    migrations = checkbag(mm, args[0])
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/migration.py", line 76, in checkbag
    for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(raw=True):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 2331, in read_messages
    yield self.seek_and_read_message_data_record((entry.chunk_pos, entry.offset), raw)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 2469, in seek_and_read_message_data_record
    msg_type = _get_message_type(connection_info)
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosbag/bag.py", line 1565, in _get_message_type
    message_type = genpy.dynamic.generate_dynamic(info.datatype, info.msg_def)[info.datatype]
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/genpy/dynamic.py", line 168, in generate_dynamic
    tmp_file.file.write(full_text.encode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2788: ordinal not in range(128)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240612/rosbag-%27unicodedecodeerror%27/) by [Sebastian Rockel](https://answers.ros.org/users/1966/sebastian-rockel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-07-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) on 2017-06-08**:
Please sign the answer as correct if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you take a look at the error you'll see that it is raised by the message definition which rosbag tries to interpret.
You possibly have personal message definitions with UTF-8 characters in it.
While the tool is written in python, there always remains the pain with UTF-8 decoding what you can see in your last line:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2788: ordinal not in range(128)

Just check which of your message definitions are UTF-8 encoded by the command line tool `file yourMessageDefinition.msg`.
If it tells you `ASCII text` the definition should be OK, if `UTF-8 Unicode text` it is not.
Just open the file and substitute all special characters like `µ` or `⊘` **even in your comments**.
If you are unsure which character in your file is special, just open up a hex editor (like `ghex`), open the file and search for characters which occupy more than one byte. Then re-build the message definitions.

---

Originally posted by [tik0](https://answers.ros.org/users/26705/tik0/) with karma: 220 on 2016-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-04-22**:
My defintion is ASCII Text and yet I got this error when running rqt_bag